# How to combine rows in a Group By Clause using SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

I have some SQL where I need it to SUM a quantity based on four variables (supplier_code, building_code, part_name, part_no). The problem is in the select statement I need to use a CASE statement to pick a building depending on the transfer_date. But by doing this I now have to use the transfer_date in the Group By which then produces three distinct rows....and I need these rows to be combined.

For example -

[image]

The three values with Napier should be combined but are not because I have had to use the transfer_date in the group by.

[image]

How do I get around this in the following SQL. Bare in mind this is a part of an UPDATE and so using a CTE does not work.

```
SELECT
    Part_Name,
    Part_No,
    Supplier_Code,
    CASE WHEN Transfer_Date > @EndDate THEN Transfer_Building ELSE Building_Code END AS 'Building_Code',
    SUM(Quantity) AS 'Incoming_Quantity'
FROM Inventory
WHERE
    Regrade = 0 AND
    (CASE WHEN Transfer_Date <= @EndDate THEN Transfer_Date ELSE Add_Date END <= @EndDate) AND
    (Add_Date >= @StartDate OR Transfer_Date >= @StartDate) AND
    Supplier_Code = 'TPP HAMSTEAD' AND Part_No = 'L32730'
GROUP BY
    Transfer_Date,
    Supplier_Code,
    Building_Code,
    Transfer_Building,
    Part_Name,
    Part_No
```

I could use a temp table but wondering if there is an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Don't group by Transfer date. Group by the entire case statement. Take everything except the SUM from your select statement and put it in the group by. Also remove the Transfer_Date from your select. If you _need_ it in there then you need to decide how to aggregate it. MAX?

Comment: The transfer date I must have left in but wasn't including it normally. Will remove out now. You should put this up as an answer.

Comment: Nick has given the answer in his comment - put the CASE statement in the group by, and remove the Transfer_Date.

Comment: Yes, but I can't mark that as correct.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a T-SQL solution (SQL Server)

```
SELECT
    Part_Name,
    Part_No,
    Supplier_Code,
    CASE 
    WHEN Transfer_Date > @EndDate 
    THEN Transfer_Building 
    ELSE Building_Code END AS 'Building_Code',
    SUM(Quantity) AS 'Incoming_Quantity'
FROM Inventory
WHERE
    Regrade = 0 AND
    (CASE WHEN Transfer_Date <= @EndDate THEN Transfer_Date 
     ELSE Add_Date END <= @EndDate) 
     AND
    (Add_Date >= @StartDate OR Transfer_Date >= @StartDate) 
    AND Supplier_Code = 'TPP HAMSTEAD' 
    AND Part_No = 'L32730'
GROUP BY
    Supplier_Code,
    Part_Name,
    Part_No,
    CASE 
    WHEN Transfer_Date > @EndDate 
    THEN Transfer_Building 
    ELSE Building_Code END
```

Comment: Just a note, no dbms is specified but your query isn't ANSI SQL compliant. (GROUP BY case expression...)

Comment: Ture. I'll add some more to the answer